# Creating/Copying permission levels in moss publishing sites

Tags: permissions, publishing-site

Does anyone know what permission levels are required to allow a user to create content but not approve it?

I’ve just spent the afternoon trying this and am more confused than when I started. For instance…

If I add a user into the Designer site permission group I can create pages – excellent, just as I would expect.

If I create a new site permissions level - let’s call it ‘customer-designer’ - by copying the Designer site permission level and then assign this ‘customer-designer’ level to a new site permission group. I then add my user into the new group and… I cannot create pages, even though the new group is based on permissions that have been directly copied from a permission set that does allow page creation

Does this make any sense? Can anyone help me to understand it?

---

**Update 1**
The issue seems to lie somewhere when the new group is created. For example if I create a new group called ‘customer-designers’ and assign it the Design permission level I still cannot create a page in the pages library.

Could someone try this for me – to see if it’s a problem on my machine or some weird behavior from Sharepoint?

Answer (score 2):

I would go into the permission levels and validate what is selected for your "Custom-Designer" level.

You specifically want to make sure that "Add and Customize Pages" is included and "Approve Items" it not included.

Also, since you do not want them approving items, you may need to define an approver group unless it is something the Site Owners are responsible for doing.

Comment: checked and double checked yet still no create permissions - just and access denied message.

Comment: Try building a new one.  I've created custom permission levels a number of times on a number of farms and I've never seen these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the group-permissionlevel assignment is applied to the rootweb. Also ensure the childwebs on which you are testing do not have unique permissions.